# Laravel Echo SocketIO with private channel

Tags: laravel, sockets, laravel-5, socket.io, laravel-echo

Hi everyone I working with Laravel Echo and SocketIO without Vue only jquery, but I have a problem with private channels here I show you that I have two events normal and private channel the normal channel (todocanales of my event HolaEvent) work fine when I lunch the event

```
use App\Events\HolaEvent;

Route::get('/fire', function () {

    $data = [
        'type'    => 'erhelloror',
        'title'   => 'new article has been published',
        'message' => 'check it out',
        'url'     => 'url',
    ];
    event(new HolaEvent($data));
    return 'done';
});
```

and in my laravel echo server console show me:

```
[03:04:47] - 5s6214Rlv51NUgnDAAAA joined channel: todocanales
[03:04:48] - QpxGvCjmaezgHn3aAAAB authenticated for: private-like-received.2jzwpAg1
[03:04:48] - QpxGvCjmaezgHn3aAAAB joined channel: private-like-received.2jzwpAg1
Channel: todocanales
Event: App\Events\HolaEvent
CHANNEL todocanales
```

and in the browser console, I get

~~~
Object {data: Object, socket: null}
~~~

all perfect, BUT with the privateChannel I have the problem Laravel Echo server don't made anything, and nothing on my console of the user logged, of course, I have running

```
php artisan queue:listen redis
```

my private channel I lunch the event in my controller

```
use App\Events\NewLikePostEvent;

$data = array(
     'user_id' => Hashids::encode($post->user_id),
     'user_name' => $name_user
);

event(new NewLikePostEvent($data));
```

In the project I have this files:

#### channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('like-received.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;
});

Broadcast::channel('todocanales', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;
});
```

#### bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://imagenes.dev:6001'
});
```

#### app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'X-Socket-Id': Echo.socketId()
            }
    });

    var receiverId = document.getElementById('receiver_id').value;


    Echo.private('like-received.'+ receiverId).listen('NewLikePostEvent', function(e) {
        console.log("Wena!, a "+e.data.user_name + " le ha gustado uno de tus aportes");
        console.log(e);
    });


    Echo.channel('todocanales').listen('HolaEvent', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

});
```

for the receiverId  I use an input hidden in the footer

```
<input type="hidden" id="receiver_id" value="{{Hashids::encode(Auth::user()->id)}}" />
```

and I have two Events

#### NewLikePostEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewLikePostEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('like-received.'.$this->data->user_id);

    }
}
```

#### HolaEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class HolaEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('todocanales');

    }
}
```

#### My laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://imagenes.dev",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "ec69415ae1adcbf2",
            "key": "578712cd13fd83f7cadef22742d6728c"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "6379"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "imagenes.dev",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

#### .env file (not all but the most important part)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ewoyjfyNjXd0FArdsfdsfsNLV7VQH35s=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://imagenes.dev
SOCKET_PORT=6001

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=imagenes
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and I have running this socket io script with node server.js

#### server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const server = require('http').Server();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis();

server.listen({
    port: process.env.SOCKET_PORT
});

redis.subscribe('*');

console.log(process.env.SOCKET_PORT);


redis.on('like-received.*', function (channel, message) {
    const event = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(event.event, channel, event.data);
});

redis.on('todocanales', function (channel, message) {
    const event = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(event.event, channel, event.data);
});
```

and finally my

#### BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

and when execute the event NewLikePostEvent with private channel in the console of queue's have a infinite get

#### Console Output

```
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:10] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:12] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:14] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:16] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:18] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:20] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:21] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:23] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:25] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:27] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:29] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:31] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:33] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:35] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:37] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:38] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:40] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:42] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:44] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
?[33m[2017-05-10 07:07:46] Processing:?[39m App\Events\NewLikePostEvent
```

PS:  I know the use of maxTries into the server is only a more onformation of my case the infinite cycle of event

I put the code because maybe can help in the future  I hope someone can help me :D

Regards!

Comment: Your question was a great answer for a question of mine. Thumbs up

Comment: Sorry I know this is old. But it's probably not a good practice to share your `APP_KEY=` or other credentials. Even for local environments I would avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed!

The problem of that the event is infinite processing and never was processed was because in my event I use:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('like-received.'.$this->data->user_id);

}
```

but $data is a array not object it was a typing error of me xD and the name of channel I replaced dot (.) for (-)

```
'like-received.'.$this->data->user_id
```

to

```
'like-received-'.$this->data['user_id']
```

finally the broadcastOn is

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('like-received-'.$this->data['user_id']);

}
```

and the rest of code I mixed with the code repo of Parth Vora :) (thanks!) https://github.com/xparthx/laravel-realtime-chat

and I dont needed to use server.js file for this we use Laravel echo server

and the app.js I changed to

```
window.Echo.private('like-received-'+window.Laravel.user).listen('NewLikePostEvent', function(e) {
    console.log("Wena!, a "+e.data.user_name + " le ha gustado uno de tus aportes");
    console.log(e);

});
```

You can see that now I use window.Laravel.user this I created on blade file

```
<script>
        window.Laravel = {
            'csrfToken': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            'user': '{{Hashids::encode(Auth::user()->id)}}'
        };
 </script>
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone because I tried 3 days on fix this hahahha :D

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very hard to troubleshoot without complete source code and running app.

So you have the issue with the private channel.

I have implemented all 3 types of channels(private, public & presence) in this chat app, maybe you can get some ideas from it:

https://github.com/xparthx/laravel-realtime-chat

Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much! I can fixed with your example code, this working I mixed my code and your code hahahaha, and in my code I have a error on event, I used $this->data->user_id but $data is a array so I need use $this->data['user_id'] this was a typing error now the event is processed :D